# Stone-Weierstrass theorem with $p(1/x)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials, approximation, approximation-theory

I am trying to prove that for a continuous $f\colon[1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and $f(x)\to a$ as $x\to\infty$ it could be approximated by $g(x)=p(1/x)$ where $p$ is a polynomial.

Comment: yes, i was thinking about that way, buy y(0) blows up...how do you justify that?

Comment: Please do not deface your questions, @marko.  Users have taken the time to answer your question, and by defacing your question you show a lack of respect for the effort they have provided.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint.** If $f: [1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, and $g(x)=f(1/x)$, then $g$ is continuous in $(0,1]$. If $f$ also has a (finite) limit, as $x\to\infty$, then 
$g$ is continuous at $0$, and altogether it is continuous in the whole closed interval $[0,1]$.

If now $p$ is a polynomial, such that 
$$
\max_{x\in [0,1]}\lvert g(x)-p(x)\rvert<\varepsilon,
$$
then
$$
\sup_{x\in [1,\infty)}\lvert f(x)-p(1/x)\rvert<\varepsilon.
$$ 
Therefore, $f$ can be approximated by polynomials of the form $p(1/x)$, by virtue of Stone-Weirestrass Theorem.

Comment: ok, i can see that follow from symmetry, and then you just need to use weierstrass theorem for first part. But i am not exactly sure how to officially prove this transition from fisrt to second equation